# How remove vertical line in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Today I bought PhpStorm and set it up with new settings, but unfortunately I don't know how to remove this vertical line in the editor (as you can see in the picture below).

[image: Vertical_line_in_PhpStorm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`

That would be `Hard wrap at` and `Visual guides` fields.

Please note that some languages (e.g. PHP etc) may have own rules for that (override aforementioned ones).

[image]