# PhpStorm - how to move divider line

Tags: formatting, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a problem with PhpStorm. I'm talking about the line which divide code.
Sometimes I have too much characters in one line and this line move next characters to next line.

I prefer to use <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> to format code and this line destroy readability of code.

How can I move this line or even delete it?

[image: PhpStorm]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of the middle grey line in the workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351583/get-rid-of-the-middle-grey-line-in-the-workspace)

Comment: NOTE: Just hiding it (right margin) will not stop code from split into 2 lines. You need to change the actual right margin value for that (make it like big enough or stuff). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654735/783119

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting **Hard wrap at** value in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML** to some big number and set **Visual guides:** accordingly. You can also try disabling **Wrap text** and setting **Wrap attributes** to *Do not wrap*.

Note that you can hide the hard wrap guide line by disabling **Show hard wrap guide (configured in Code Style options)** in **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**, but hiding it won't prevent code from being wrapped (as @LazyOne mentioned in his comment)